# how to use jq to merge/join/concat values with the same key

Tags: json, join, merge, concatenation, jq

I need to aggregate values by key. Example JSON input is:

```
$ cat json | jq 
[
  {
    "key": "john",
    "value": "ontario"
  },
  {
    "key": "ryan",
    "value": "chicago"
  },
  {
    "key": "ryan",
    "value": "illinois"
  },
  {
    "key": "john",
    "value": "toronto"
  },
]
```

Is it possible and if so how to merge/join/concat values with the same key so that the result is:

```
[
  {
    "key": "john",
    "value": "toronto ontario"
  },
  {
    "key": "ryan",
    "value": "illinois chicago"
  },
]
```

I am targetting JQ specifically because of its ease of use from cfengine.

Answer (score 5):

Group the pairs by key, then combine the values.

```
group_by(.key) | map({key:.[0].key,value:(map(.value) | join(" "))})
```

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem, I prefer to avoid the overhead of sorting, and to guarantee that the ordering of the objects in the input is respected.

Here's one approach that assumes the values associated with "key" and "value" are all strings (as is the case in the example).  This assumption makes it easy to avoid an inefficient lookup:

```
def merge_by_key(separator):
  reduce .[] as $o
    ({}; $o["key"] as $k
         | if .[$k] then .[$k] += (separator + $o["value"])
           else .[$k] = $o["value"] end);

merge_by_key(" ") | to_entries
```

Output:

```
[{"key":"john","value":"ontario toronto"},
 {"key":"ryan","value":"chicago illinois"}]
```

#### Generic solution

```
def merge_at_key(separator):
  reduce .[] as $o
    ([];
     $o["key"] as $k
     | (map(.key) | index($k)) as $i
     | if $i then (.[$i] | .value) += (separator + $o["value"])
       else . + [$o] end);
```